# Pywinauto click on item in submenu of context menu

Tags: python, wpf, python-2.7, pywinauto

I'v like to ask if there is any possibilities to click in submenu of contextmenu.

Basic click on some of manuitem is basic (example of code):

```
app = Desktop(backend='uia').window(best_match='ItemTemplates')
win = app.window(best_match='Visual Web Developer')
win.click_input(button='right')

app = Desktop(backend='uia').window(best_match='Context')
win = app.window(best_match='Send To')
win.click_input()
```

In this code i will right click element of explorer, then click to ,,Send to" all elements of right click menu are in *u'Context'*. Submenu items are a mystery.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dehD3.png)

Comment: Context menu is usually top level window so you should restart from desktop to catch the submenus.

Comment: It doesnt help, still can not find submenu items of right click menu.

Comment: What do you see in `Inspect.exe`? Can you post a screenshot(s)? Tools to download: https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool